# Object with indeterminate shape

Tags: javascript, typescript

In my codebase I have several exported method dealing with API calls. Each of these methods take a `param` argument which is always an object but of indeterminate shape, e.g.

```
export {
  getSomething: (param: any) => getSomething(param),
  ...
}
```

`param` could be something like:

```
 { userId: "123" } || { userId: "123", otherId: "234", ... } etc.
```

Here's `getSomething` definition:

```
function getSomething(param: { userId: string; }) {
  ...
}
```

For now the only solution I've found (which I'm not satisfied with) could be something like this:

```
  interface Param {
    [key: string]: string;
  }

  export {
    getSomething: (param: Param) => getSomething(param),
    ...
  }

  // in another file
  function getSomething(param: Param) {}
```

But I'm loosing the description of what my function expects exactly as an argument

How could I get rid of type `any` here and specify that `param` is an object of indeterminate shape and with variable number of keys?

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: if you truly accept any parameter shape, there's nothing else you can do. Now, if there's a lot of possible shapes your object could accept to, but they are a limited subset you know in advance, there are a couple of options: Make a `Record<all keys you would accept, string>` which is the same as you've done now (but specifying which keys are, instead of any key), or create an interface with each combination and make `param: Type1 | Type2 |...` and use type guard to determine

if you need to do different stuff depending on which type is, in order to know which one is you will use type guards

Comment: What are you unhappy about the structure of your code or that param is not specific enough?

Comment: @MacD with `(param: Param) => ...` the function argument is less descriptive than with `(param: { userId: string; }) => ...`

Answer (score 1):

I do think that your solution is correct. Using interface segregation is a SOLID principle.

Also, your method `getSomething` ony need to use `key` all the other attributes of param is not needed.

I do think that's the right way to be clean code and SOLID.

Answer (score 1):

You can constrain your Param further if you want using unions. This will allow it to be a set of specific possible types and the more general indexer you have. You can then have the calling function use a specific member of the union to provide a specific definition for your exported function.

```
type Param  = {[key: string]: string} | {a:number} | {a:boolean, b:string, c?:never}

function getSomething(param: Param) {}

export const exp = {
    getSomething: (param: {a:number}) => getSomething(param), //matches {a:number}
    getSomething2: (param: {a:string}) => getSomething(param) //matches {[key:string]: string}
  }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBAKBDATogthAvBA3hRcArBAL4QD05A8gNIBQUWu+cARABYjDAD2rpFavUbY8BCBy69WAGggAjNp258BlWgyZ4AxmzDIAnvzLr6m0QqUBLWSwjET5MAYAOAZ23IrLyNp5oXYEQrADs3OjpnFxAEFHQtCABtAGsQAzg3fVCAcwBdDKyQ7IEAH2ZxEIBXNHkQZFLyuHkeHlBEELlFCEyvIrltAH44EJAANzrSCIAzSpDtMCseEIhs8ABlf3B2HIAKFzi0OCRUNABKZhIIkCgXHmRfJcyIa5ctOggPlfXNsG2iuD2BzgYmG1Vq9RI50wAD4vmANmgtrt9idTnJKGhEGBtJw3LgCFUanVLp84QikUUAEwAlHoYF2Ho5UhQ2GreE-P7ZQGowSY7G43ApNIwRlFfLdQrZS6XIA)